# termination of xcode project due to memory error while running unity game

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a game made *using unity for android and IOS device*. Game works fine in android device. *When I run the game on IOS device using Xcode, game runs over 4-6 minutes and then terminates automatically showing a dialog box saying* "**The app** "**carRacing" on iphone quit unexpectedly. Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Error**"

[image]

I have two scenes in my game "**menu scene**" and "**game scene*". The memory error usually occurs when switching between these two scenes. In Xcode, I use a navigator debugger** to view the **cpu usage, memory usage** of the *game during runtime*. The cpu usage and memory usage is **very high while switching the scene** from **menu scene** to **game scene** or **vice-versa.**

Comment: How are you switching between scenes? Can we see the code?

Comment: @manelizzard , I am switching scenes simply by using **SceneManager.LoadScene("scene"). I am using google admob** for showing ads. When I remove the admob part, the game runs with no error. But when the **admob part is included, the game runs only for 4-5 min and then terminates showing memory error** as I mentioned above.